# Document conversion error when rails app sends word docs, outlook emails from SQLServer db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, ms-access

I have a rails application which among other things is an alternate way for internal customers to view saved business documents.  word docs emails and PDFs are entered into my DB running on SQL Server 10 through a Access 10 application, and embedded via file download into a Bound Object Frame control in Access.

The the binary data is saved into the sql database back-end with an associated record.  Documents are easily stored and read using the access front end, but I'm having trouble getting the files out of the DB and sent to a client through the Rails app.

The field in which the docs are stores is a SQL Server varbinary(max) field.

I try to read send it down to the browser in the following manner.

```
doc = @attachment.document
send_data doc, :filename => 'foo.docx'
```

The browser spawns the file download/open dialog and identifies it as an MS Word doc, but the file delivered is unreadable (even though it delivers approximately right number of bytes.)

When I try using, for example, with a word document:

```
send_data doc, :type => "application/msword", :filename => 'foo.docx'
```

I get the following error from the controller:

```
"\x8F" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8
```

suggestions, advice apprecaited.

Comment: Have you tried using [send_file](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_file) instead?

Comment: Well, the thing is there's no file.  The data is extracted from the SQL DB, not form a file.  I could write the data to a file and then send that, but I can't see how that would help really.